# Deselect widget in callback function in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I used TKinter in python2.

My code is as follow.

```
from Tkinter import *  


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None,w=1000,h=600):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.createWidgets(master,w,h)

    def getRadio(self,widget):
        widget.deselect()


    def createWidgets(self, master,w,h):
        ConfigPane=Frame(master,bg='lightblue',width=int((w/6)*4),height=int(h/3),padx=5,pady=5)
        DisplayPane=Frame(master,bg='DarkOliveGreen1',width=int((w/6)*4),height=int((h/3)*2),padx=5,pady=5)
        HyperPane=Frame(master,bg='khaki1',width=int((w/6)*2),height=h,padx=5,pady=5)
        # layout all of the main containers
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)        
        ConfigPane.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,rowspan=1, sticky=W+N)
        DisplayPane.grid(row=1,columnspan=4,rowspan=2, sticky=W+S)
        HyperPane.grid(row=0,column=5,columnspan=2,rowspan=3, sticky=E+N+S)
        # create the widgets for the top frame
        var=StringVar()
        RegNet = Radiobutton(ConfigPane, text='RegNet',variable=var,pady=10,padx=10,width=10,anchor='w',command=lambda:self.getRadio(RegNet))
        RegNet.grid(row=0,column=0)           
        InceptionNet = Radiobutton(ConfigPane, text='InceptionNet',variable=var,pady=1,padx=10,width=10,anchor='w',command=lambda:self.getRadio(InceptionNet))
        InceptionNet .grid(row=1,column=0)
        ResNet = Radiobutton(ConfigPane, text='ResNet',variable=var,pady=8,padx=10,width=10,anchor='w',command=lambda:self.getRadio(ResNet))
        ResNet.grid(row=2,column=0)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry(str(width)+'x'+str(height))
    app = Application(master=root,w=width,h=height)
    app.master.title('Deep Learning Reconfigurable Platform')
    app.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

When I click the radiobutton, the black dot at the button is supposed to disappear, but it doesn't. How can I make it work?

Comment: Read [radiobutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Every radiobutton needs a distinct `value`, otherwise they all have the same value and thus show the same state. The value is how tkinter knows which button in a set of buttons should be selected.

You probably shouldn't be calling `deselect` in the callback -- that makes your buttons effectively useless, since any attempt by the user to choose one will cause whatever they clicked on to immediately be deselected. It will become impossible for them to select anything.

Comment: that is interesting. My Radiobutton doesn't change when I click the button. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The key elements:

- The "var", must be defined in scope of Class, if not it is destroyed when exiting the createWidget method and you would need to navigate through the widgets to get the selected one.
- The RadioButtons are missing the value attribute, defining what is the value to be set to the "var" when selected.

Here is the updated code; updated for Python3 (changed the module tkinter name)

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    var = None
    def __init__(self, master=None,w=1000,h=600):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.var.set(1)
        self.createWidgets(master, w, h)

    def show_choice(self):
        #for widget in widgets:
         #   widget.deselect()
        print(self.var.get())
        return


    def createWidgets(self, master,w,h):
        ConfigPane=Frame(master,bg='lightblue',width=int((w/6)*4),height=int(h/3),padx=5,pady=5)
        DisplayPane=Frame(master,bg='DarkOliveGreen1',width=int((w/6)*4),height=int((h/3)*2),padx=5,pady=5)
        HyperPane=Frame(master,bg='khaki1',width=int((w/6)*2),height=h,padx=5,pady=5)
        # layout all of the main containers
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        ConfigPane.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,rowspan=1, sticky=W+N)
        DisplayPane.grid(row=1,columnspan=4,rowspan=2, sticky=W+S)
        HyperPane.grid(row=0,column=5,columnspan=2,rowspan=3, sticky=E+N+S)
        # create the widgets for the top frame
        RegNet = Radiobutton(ConfigPane, text='RegNet',variable=self.var,pady=10,padx=10,width=10,anchor='w', value=1, command=self.show_choice)
        RegNet.grid(row=0,column=0)
        InceptionNet = Radiobutton(ConfigPane, text='InceptionNet',variable=self.var,pady=1,padx=10,width=10,anchor='w', value=2, command=self.show_choice)
        InceptionNet.grid(row=1,column=0)
        ResNet = Radiobutton(ConfigPane, text='ResNet',variable=self.var,pady=8,padx=10,width=10,anchor='w', value=3, command=self.show_choice)
        ResNet.grid(row=2,column=0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry(str(width)+'x'+str(height))
    app = Application(master=root,w=width,h=height)
    app.master.title('Deep Learning Reconfigurable Platform')
    app.mainloop()
    # root.destroy()
```

Comment: thanks, so how can I select and deselect the RadioButton at the applcation?

Comment: My Radiobutton doesn't change when I click the button. What could be wrong?